# Which Sitecore versions does Horizon 9.3.0 support?

Tags: horizon

On the Horizon 9.3.0 "On-premise installation guide" the first prerequisites is "Sitecore Experience Platform 9.3 or later version". 
However, the release notes say that  "Horizon 9.3.0 supports Sitecore Experience Platform 9.1 and 9.1.1".

Is Horizon backward compatible with older versions of Sitecore?
If Horizon supports Sitecore 9.1 why it does not support Sitecore 9.2?

Note: I did subscribe to the Sitecore Feedback program. As soon as I get access I will share my feedback with Sitecore.
**Sitecore feedback:**
https://www.sitecore.com/company/contact-us/product-feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horizon 9.3 is compatible just with Sitecore XP 9.3

You can find this information on Sitecore Modules compatibility table: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Vlad. I thought the same since Horizon was released with Sitecore 9.3. However, I forgot to verify it from the Sitecore Compatible table.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore horizon only compatible with sitecore 9.3 initial release.no sitecore horizon dont have backward compatibility